# Schema Markup for Sub-Brand Product Website

Tags: schema.org, knowledge-graph

I am trying to improve my website's SEO by getting our results to appear in the Knowledge Graph. The challenge I am having is that the website is for a product sold by a sub-brand of a larger organisation. What would be the best way to categorise this in Schema markup? Currently it is not appearing by using the sub-brand name in "*Organization*","*name*".

For example, what would the website markup be for **PlayStation** being part of the larger organisation of **Sony**? Are there defined categories for this in Schema?

Comment: I don't think that Google uses schema markup as a data source for knowledge panels anymore.   To get a knowledge panel for your organization you need to have a profile on a site that Google trusts for that data.   Google uses sources like Wikipedia, LinkedIn, Crunchbase, Reuters, and Bloomberg.  See https://searchengineland.com/how-to-get-a-knowledge-panel-for-your-brand-even-without-wikipedia-338642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`subOrganization`](https://schema.org/subOrganization) property is probably what you need, for example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
    <div itemprop="name">Sony</div>
    <div>…</div>
    <div itemprop="subOrganization" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
        <div itemprop="name">PlayStation</div>
        <div>…</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This can then go on both playstation.com and sony.com. I would however add all of the pertinent details to the subOrganization itemtype that one would normally add to the Organization itemtype, e.g. URL, @ID, even physical address details concerning Playstation's headquarters.